# Meaning of 様になる

Tags: translation

I was reading a story on Hukumusume.

In [this story](http://hukumusume.com/douwa/pc/jap/01/01.htm), there is the following sentence:

```
怒ったネコは、それからずっと、ネズミを見ると追いかける様になりました。
```

[Denshi Jisho](http://classic.jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%09&eng=&dict=edict) says that `様になる`  means "to look good". Here clearly it seems to mean "it came to this...". Am I right?

Comment: If you listen to the audio transcription on that page, you'll hear 見ると追いかける**よう**になりました

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E6%A7%98%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B definition on Jisho.org